# Xib file with Custom View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, xib

I have a .xib file that it's file's owner is a UIViewController. Like shown in the picture.

The view in the .xib file is part of a custom UIView. So my problem is that my IBOutlets are throwing me nil values when I try to add a corner radius to the buttons. (Yes, my IBOutlets are connected)

```
class MenuView: UIView {

// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var chatButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var animationButton: UIButton!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
    backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive           = true
    backgroundImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive   = true
    backgroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive     = true

    chatButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    animationButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8
}

// MARK: - BackgroundImage
private var backgroundImage: UIImageView  = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bg_home_menu"))
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()
}
```

So my question is, why am I getting nil values for my outlets? and What could I do to fix it?

I'm trying to do this approach of using both the interface builder and programmatic interface.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In order for the IBOutlers to work, I have to move the code that set the corner radius to the awakeFromNib function.

init(coder) it is initializing the view and does not have reference to the outlets yet. In awakeFromNib the is called after the initialization is done and the outlets should not be nil there.